# How do I run a jquery function after the a div have been added to the dom?

Tags: jquery, dom

I am using a plugin that creates an accordion using jquery.  However, my jquery function is running before the dom has been manipulated and the div id I am targeting in my function has been created.  Here is my function.

```
jQuery('#_Offer_Something').click(function(){

      if( !confirm('Delete?') ) { //show confirm dialog
            return false; //do nothing if cancel is clicked (prevent the browser from following clicked link)
      }else{
           window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); 
    }
});
```

So basically this doesn't work because the div doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

In your specific case you can use: [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
(function($){  // remap the '$' symbol to jQuery

   $(document).on('click', '#_Offer_Something',function(){
   // ^^^^ or 'body' or a parent element
       if( !confirm('Delete?') ) { //show confirm dialog
            return false; //do nothing if cancel is clicked (prevent the browser from following clicked link)
       }else{
            window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); 
       }
   });

})(jQuery);
```

The above will act as the now deprecated jQuery `.live()` method.
Make sure you placed your jQuery `<script>` tag before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: Do I use this function inside my document.ready function instead of or outside of as I have other functions inside document.ready

Comment: @Nicola , using `(function($){ /*..code here..*/ })(jQuery);` is a very practical replacement for the common `$(document).ready(){` call, so use it like one.

Comment: ok thanks, I'm using wordpress and can't use the familiar $ and have to use jQuery instead, would this replacement function let me use $?

Comment: I don't work with Wordpress (one day I will), but I remember I sugested this replacement to a friend of mine and it worked like a charm! Test it and PLEASE let me know!

Comment: hehe it does it works, no more writing jQuery every time, cheers!

Comment: YEAH! that's the exact reason I suggested it to a firend, he was writing (don't ask me why) *jQuery_SomethingLongHere* over and over again!! :)

Comment: can you help with this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267532/how-can-i-add-a-class-with-jquery-once-dynamic-loading-is-finished

Answer (score 2):

If your DOM object is created dynamically sometime after the page has loaded, then you will want to use delegated event handling so that events from it will be picked up, even if your event handler is installed before the relevant object.  You can do that with jQuery 1.7+ using the dynamic form of `.on()`:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#_Offer_Something', function(){

      if( !confirm('Delete?') ) { //show confirm dialog
            return false; //do nothing if cancel is clicked (prevent the browser from following clicked link)
      }else{
           window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); 
    }
});
```

Technically, the way this works is that all click events bubble up the ancestor chain (unless some object along the way stops the bubbling process).  In this case, we install a click handler on the `document` object and it watches for click events that originate on an object that matches the `#_Offer_Something` selector.

For best performance, you wouldn't actually bind this event handler to the `document` object.  Instead, you would pick a static parent object (some parent of `#_Offer_Something`) that does exist at the time you install the event handler.  I picked the `document` object here only because you didn't disclose the rest of your HTML so I don't know what a better choice would be.

Comment: @Guy - there is no other answer that uses the same code I proposed.  Your answer uses static event handling.  Mine uses delegated event handling.  Yours will work fine if the `#_Offer_Something` object exists at the time the event handler is installed.  Mine will work even if that object is created some time after the event handler is installed.  Our answers both use `.on()`, but are fundamentally different approaches.

Comment: thanks for your answer, its worked.  Do I use this function inside my document.ready function instead of or outside of as I have other functions inside document.ready?

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `on` binding or bind the element only after it has been inserted. Refer to http://api.jquery.com/on/ for examples. Quick example:

```
$(document).on('click', '#_Offer_Something', function(){});
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work.  My function is working because using it directly in chromes console makes it work

Comment: I assure you that this works. Make sure you have an up to date jQuery version. Edit: funny me, I actually made a mistake.

Comment: ahh yeh, when I changed it to document it worked.  So do I use this function inside my document.ready function instead of or outside of as I have other functions inside document.ready

Comment: @Guy - it's kind of ironic that you posted a comment to my answer asking me "Why did I post the same answer as yours?" and then you realized that I had a better solution than yours so you changed yours to match mine.  Nice.

Comment: @jfriend00, Well that's not true. I simply corrected the error I made *in the example*. No way is my answer different from yours otherwise.

Comment: @Guy - your edit history shows what you originally had.  This is what was in your answer when I wrote mine: `$('#_Offer_Something').on('click', function(){});` and when you protested that I was posting the same thing you had.  Anyway, I just thought it was amusing.

Comment: @jfriend00, do you need help with English? `I simply corrected the error I made in the example.` Which is exactly what you've reposting. Again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ... code here ...
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
  ... Code here ...
});
```