# How can I add a class with jquery once dynamic loading is finished?

Tags: jquery

I need to add a class to an `<a>` that is added programmatically. When I call `addClass` it doesn't add it, this is I assume because the plugin hasn't finished installing all it's bits and pieces so the anchor isn't there yet.

The page is [here](http://nicolaelvin.com/community/). It's the login bar at the top. I want to add a class to the login and sign up buttons e.g.

```
jQuery('.bp-login a').addClass('simplemodal-login');
jQuery('.bp-signup a').addClass('simplemodal-register');
```

The HTML for that section is

```
<ul class="main-nav">
<li class="bp-login no-arrow">
    <a href="http://nicolaelvin.com/community/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fnicolaelvin.com%2Fcommunity">Log In
    </a>
</li>
<li class="bp-signup no-arrow">
     <a href="http://nicolaelvin.com/community/register/">Sign Up
     </a>
</li>
...</ul>
```

Comment: Do you install some plugin like activeX control and after that you want to add?

Comment: No its wordpress and a plugin loads, and after that I want to add, but its a similar thing

Comment: I know about .on() but I think this only works with events

Comment: The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements but you have to check if document controls are ready to use and that you get in ready method

Comment: Hi Nix. Give an example of the loaded html and Ill explain

Comment: have updated my question

Comment: What code are you using to load the new elements?

Comment: Can you show the relevant html before and after the plugin loaded? That would help a lot.

Comment: Oh, and your link is now un-broken. Though there are *two* 'log in' options. On the left it takes me to a Wordpress login page, and on the right there's a modal to fill out. I'm assuming it's the one on the right?

Comment: it's a wordpress plugin that just does it's thing

Comment: @Nicola updated my answer after looking at your page. Check it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
jQuery(function() {

    var modal_check = setInterval(function(){

        if(jQuery('.simplemodal-login').length > 1){
            clearInterval(modal_check);
            jQuery('.bp-login a').addClass('simplemodal-login');
            jQuery('.bp-signup a').addClass('simplemodal-register');
        }

    },100);

});​
```

This waits until the dom is ready then checks every 10th of a second to see if the modal plugin has loaded. Once the plugin has loaded it stops the interval and adds the class.

Comment: I suppose that plugin should have some callback for this action.

Comment: Isn't there any jQuery event that could be used instead of setInterval?

Comment: @PetrPeller There could be a `onload` callback for the plugin mentioned but without knowing that an interval is the only other option.

Answer (score -1):

You should wait until DOM is ready.

```
$(function () {
  $(element).addClass('hello');
});
```

Comment: that doesn't work because the element hasn't been added as normal, it's done with jquery so I think as far as jQuery knows, it's done, when it's isn't. If that makes sense...